# Cannot find USB camera index with VideoCapture() OpenCV

Tags: usb, raspberrypi, camera, opencv

I'm trying to connect a GoPro 10 to RPi5 and work with OpenCV library.
I'm having issues to find "camera index" in order to create VideoCamera object.
I followed https://github.com/jschmid1/gopro_as_webcam_on_linux and it works well with VLC.

On HW perspective, the xHCI (USB Controller) sees the GoPro, $ lsusb shows the GoPro. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOcEp.jpg)

The OS also recognize the GoPro and assign it to available video device interfaces, using the command: $ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy5U2.jpg)

Comment: Add yourself to the `video` group with `sudo adduser $USER video`, then logoff and login. Groups are set up at `login` time.